# sr-speedbar width size options on start not working

Tags: init-file, window, speedbar, start-up

By default, [sr-speedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar) seems to always want to take 50% of available window space.

I'm trying to change it's default size to something smaller (like 40 px), but I can't seem to figure out how as the option `sr-speedbar-width-x` doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's a snippet from my init.el.  All the other options are working just fine

```
(setq 
    sr-speedbar-width-x 40
    speedbar-use-images nil
    speedbar-show-unknown-files t
    sr-speedbar-right-side nil
    )

(when window-system
    (sr-speedbar-open))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have a typo in your width setup or that variable existed in an older version of `sr-speedbar`.

The variable to configure width in the current version is `sr-speedbar-width` (without the '-x').

Here is how to configure the width:

- **First** and foremost, close the speedbar if open. This is a crucial step because `sr-speedbar` "remembers" the speedbar width when closing. So if you change the value of `sr-speedbar-width` and then close the speedbar ( `sr-speedbar-close` ), that variable will be overwritten with the current width of speedbar.
- Then, do `(setq sr-speedbar-width 40)`.

I have tested this to work with version *20140914.2339* of [`sr-speedbar`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sr-speedbar.el) on emacs 24.4.

Comment: "sr-speedbar-width-x" was the problem as it should have been "sr-speedbar-width".

Comment: I have similar problems to Zamicol, and the tip does not work. This is what I have.

```(use-package speedbar
  :config
  (setq speedbar-use-images nil
        speedbar-show-unknown-files t)
  (use-package sr-speedbar
    :ensure t
    :config
    (setq sr-speedbar-right-side nil
          sr-speedbar-max-width 40
          sr-speedbar-width 30
          sr-speedbar-default-width 30
          sr-speedbar-skip-other-window-p t)))```

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas I eval'd your use-package snippet and it works fine. I then **closed sr-speedbar first**, then changed the `sr-speedbar-width`, re-eval'd the use-package snippet and reopened sr-speedbar and the width change was effective.